# Can't see the source code in chrome after emiting source maps using webback

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-4

I enabled `Enable JavaScript source maps` and `Enable CSS source maps` in my chrome.

The source code in my IDE:

```
Promise.resolve().finally();

class MySpecialClass {

}

export default (text = "11112221") => {
    const element = document.createElement("div");

    element.innerHTML = text;
    new MySpecialClass();
    return element;
};
```

.babelrc: (`ie: 7` doesn't have `classes` and `const`)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "ie": 7,
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "10",
          "safari": "11.1",
          "esmodules": false
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? "development" : "production",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        // default output directory: "dist" under the main folder.
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        babelrc: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Webpack demo",
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        stats: "errors-only",
        host: process.env.HOST,
        port: process.env.PORT,
        open: true, // Open the page in browser
    },
};
```

Chrome dev tools: (I can see the CSS as expected but not my JS code)

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

My playground-project repository: https://github.com/stavalfi/webpack-demo

Comment: They should all be visible under that `webpack://` in the left bar. Do you see them in there?

Comment: Yes! And the debugging is working like magic! Please post an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: It is under: `webback://./src/`

Answer (score 0):

Although `webpack:///./src/` does work, you really want to click on a file in console.logs which devtools will automatically point you to the right file.

You can fix the mapping of files in devtools with this:

```
output: {
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: (info) => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what is `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate`, `info.absoluteResourcePath` and what you are trying to replace? Thanks again!

Comment: Shalom, @StavAlfi, It's a relatively new issue with webpack. You can read all about it [Link to webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6400#issuecomment-361848494)